# How to send frames from webcam to server and back?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, websocket, streaming

This might seem pretty odd but here is my situation, I want to get frames from the webcam ( at a reasonable FPS ) and send those frames to my server. The server does some processing and returns the image. Now I want to display the image in the browser.

Stream of Webcam Frames -> Server -> Process -> Send Frame back -> Display the frame like a video.

The main problem I am facing now is

1. Capturing frames from the webcam at a reasonable frame rate (20 ~ 30).
2. Displaying images got back from the server in some HTML element like a video.

Here is what I have now,

### Capturing and sending data to server

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
.then((strm) =>
{
    myVideo.srcObject = strm; // myVideo is an HTML video element
    imageCapture = new ImageCapture(stream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
});

ws.onopen = () => setInterval(captureImage, 1000 / FPS); // ws is new WebSocket(WS_URL)
```

### Receiving and showing image

```
ws.onmessage = (message) => drawCanvas(previewCtx, message.data); // previewCtx is canvas.getContext('2d')

async function drawCanvas(ctx, data) // ctx is a canvas context
{
    const img = await createImageBitmap(data); // Create image bitmap from blob

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
```

As you could have guessed this approach doesn't work. I cant get FPS of anything higher than 3 or 4. And also got this dom error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The associated Track is in an invalid state
```

I think I can solve this error by waiting for image capture to finish before calling image capture again, but this approach won't work due to the extremely low FPS.

So here is my question :

1. A faster method to capture frames.
2. Some way to display received frames.

And just in case anybody knows is there any optimization I can make to get the latency as low as possible. Like from capturing webcam to displaying the same frame.

Just for the sake of it here is my server-side code,

```
wsServer.on('connection', (ws, req) =>
{
    ws.on('message', async data =>
    {
        if (ws.readyState === ws.OPEN)
            ws.send(data); // For now I just send back what is received.
    });
});
```

**NB: I am ready to make any change in the serverside code if necessary.**

Comment: Why not use WebRTC and send it to server using webRTC?

Comment: @bugwheels94 How would I go about doing that. I would prefer to send each frame of video as separate images so it would be easier to process serverside. I want to minimize round trip latency as much as possible is this possible with WebRTC.

Comment: @bugwheels94 Could you post a detailed answer. I am completely confused about this.